# Visual Studio 2010 source server alert crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, source-server

I just installed VS2010 Beta 2. When it opens for the first time it gives me a security error that "use source server only if you trust the origin blah blah". At this time VS crashes. VS itself comes up normally, but since the source server alert pops up, it is in a modal window, so VS stops accepting input until I dismiss the alert, which I can't do.

I don't really need source server; so if I can figure out how to disable it through the registry or some similar way, it would be good enough for me.

I have VS 2008 on the same box, and it indeed has source server (from Microsoft) enabled; but the problem remains, even if I disable it in VS 2008. Apparently, installation migrated this setting, and now wants me to confirm that I understand the risk.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: After all its a beta version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it in the registry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Debugger
```

The registry key is `UseSourceServer` and you need to set it to `0`.